# App gradle and xml file is missing content while opening

Tags: android, xml, android-gradle-plugin

When I try opening the `xml` and `gradle` file in Android Studio,

Both of my files are missing the original content and is replaced by another content.
Below are the screenshots:

XML File

[image: xml file]

Gradle File

[image: Gradle File]

Every day I open the files they behave like this. Currently I use my backup to replace the file contents but I need a solution to this problem. I don't know why this happens.

Can anyone please suggest me a solution? Or is there any other alternatives please suggest. I'm kinda stuck with this for days now.

This screenshot when i sync.

Gradle Sync
[image]

Comment: your android studio version and OS name please?

Comment: Studio Version : 3.3 
Development OS: windows 10
Android OS: 28

Comment: sync project with gradle fiels.

Comment: Gradle Sync wont work as the file contents are wrong and if I did sync it never stops running.

Comment: delete your build file and try again.

Answer (score 1):

> **From what I am seeing this seems like the issue with the gradle and**
>   **android studio setting version of yours.**

Here is what you can do as first try!
totally **no Harm will happen following the steps**

1:  go to file menu and close project

2:  close all instanses of android studio

3:  then go to . C:\users\YOUR_USER_NAME\

4:  you will see property files like .  .gradle, .androidStudio3.3

> deleting that old .gradle file will delete all the gradle cache
>   deleting the .androidStudio3.3 file will delete the basic settings of
>   android studio you did like the custom keymap,plugins,themes etc
>   (optional)

5:   so delete both those files mentioned above

6:  after deleting those just fire up android studio, follow the steps and create a new project

step 6:  creating a new project will make the android studio to download a fresh pack of gradle for your system, and new setting will be made.

6:  when you are able to build the application then open your old project and see if the old error persists

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue many a times in IntelliJ.

1. Disable offline mode in gradle settings.
2. Use latest gradle distribution. Perhaps 4.6+
3. Delete existing .gradle file. Since I work on Linux machine, it is in the 
   Idea folder. Or in windows, you should find it in AppData.
4. Refresh gradle.

Refresh gradle might take a while. If problem persists, then try installing gradle files from terminal and copy to .gradle file.